# Qt5 Static Build cannot open input file "/SDK/lib/x86.obj"

Tags: c++, qt, build, static, installation

I'm trying to do a static build of Qt, but I get an error:

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'SDK\Lib\x86.obj'
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"c:\Development\Visual Studio 2010\VC\BIN\link.EXE"'
 : return code '0x49d'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"c:\Development\Visual Studio 2010\VC\BIN\nmake.exe"
' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cd' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cd' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cd' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
```

I'm using Windows 7 x64, and have Perl and Python in the system Path. I've been using [this](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Building_Qt_5_from_Git) guide to download Qt. (git repository)  Windows SDK 7.1 is installed as well, using the msvc2010 compiler. I also have another compilation of Qt that is shared, and that works just fine. The static build of Qt i'm trying to build is in a different directory.

It's just when I pass the -static option to the Qt configure, is when this error pops up.

My configure command looks like this

```
configure -static- mp -nomake tests -nomake examples -release -developer-build -opensource
```

Comment: @ACB I have to add libraries? I'm just building the Qt libraries statically so I can do static builds later on. Like, I'm building Qt5, not a project statically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it was a corrupt build path, or something.

I actually went to reformat my hard drive and do a clean install of Win7 x64. After that a static compile of Qt successfully completed on the first try. To others who might have this problem I would suggest using a registry cleaner and whatnot to see if you can completely clear it.

Another thing I changed; I added the "*-opengl desktop*" to configure.exe because I have a relatively good graphics card and decided not to install the DirectX SDK.